# Is there a way to let a manager use the "log in as another user" permission, but only as their own subordinates in the role hierarchy?

Tags: permissions, user-management, role-hierarchy

I have been scaling back system permissions across many non-admin profiles in our org, but one manager has complained that he needs to be able to log in as his reps in order to troubleshoot various things.  I see his point, but I don't want him to be able to log in as an admin of course.  Is there any way to restrict who you can log in as under the "Log in as another User" permission, based on the role hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. What you need is something called delegated administration. In delegated administration, you specify a user (or users) that can login as other users, and then specify which users they can login as (which may be roles and subordinates). However, you'll essentially need to set up this feature for each user you want to be a delegated administrator. See [Delegated Administrative Duties](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=admin_delegate.htm&siteLang=en_US) for more information.